# How do I make a new section that I can click a button so it scrolls to that?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a section below my main page (The one you see when you enter the site) and I got a projects button that you can click on that takes you to the projects section.

BUT how do you like move something? I can't figure out of the life of me on how to actually move my text that is supposed to be about my projects, I want it further down the site... but it ruins the flow of the site idk how to describe it.

I haven't really tried anyuthing. i tried moving it but it ruins the site

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: [Linking to an element on the same page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#linking_to_an_element_on_the_same_page) and [scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are trying to make the projects section scroll into view when clicked on the projects button in the 'main page'.

This can be achieved in two ways.

1. Without JS
   Use an anchor tag `<a>` tag with the id of the projects section as the href.

   `<a href="#projects">Go to Projects</a>`
2. Using JS scrollIntoView

   `var projectsSection = document.getElementById("projects");`
   `projectsSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });`

Check the below code snippet for an example using both methods.

```js
const scrollToProjects = () => {
  var projectsSection = document.getElementById("projects");
  projectsSection.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}
```

```css
.main {
  background: #999;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}

.projects {
  background: #555;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1>Main page (The one you see when you enter the site)
  </h1>
  <button onclick="scrollToProjects()">Go to Projects (Using JS)</button>
  <br>
  <a href="#projects">Go to Projects (using anchor tag)</a>
</div>
<div class="projects" id="projects">
  <h1>
    Projects
  </h1>
</div>
```